# Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to parse JaCoCo XML report: jacoco.exec

Tags: java, sonarqube, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, jacoco-plugin

I am trying to publish my coverage report generated by Jacoco plugin - jacoco.exec. But I get the below exception with the mentioned sonar and Jacoco configuration.

**SonarCube version** 6.7.7

```
[ERROR] Coverage report 'jacoco.exec' could not be read/imported. Error: {}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to parse JaCoCo XML report: jacoco.exec
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.XmlReportParser.parse(XmlReportParser.java:96)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoSensor.importReport(JacocoSensor.java:73)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoSensor.importReports(JacocoSensor.java:64)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoSensor.execute(JacocoSensor.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:177)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:291)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:286)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:264)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:65)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.setInputSource(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:212)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.<init>(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.getXMLStreamReaderImpl(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:262)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.createXMLStreamReader(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:134)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.XmlReportParser.parse(XmlReportParser.java:46)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:212)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:286)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1895)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.arrangeCapacity(XMLEntityScanner.java:1761)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(XMLEntityScanner.java:1829)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$XMLDeclDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:749)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.setInputSource(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:202)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

**Sonar Configuration**:
Configuration details of sonar plugin mentioned in maven

```
<sonar.jacoco.reportPath>target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
<sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>target/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
<sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
<sonar.verbose>true</sonar.verbose>
<sonar.java.source>8</sonar.java.source>
```

**Jacoco Configuration**
Configuration details of Jacoco plugin mentioned in maven

```
      <org.jacoco.version>0.8.1</org.jacoco.version>
      <profile>
            <id>sonar-coverage</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0.603</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>jacoco</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.jacoco.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <append>true</append>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>agent-for-unit-test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>agent-for-integration-test</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-site</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Am I missing any configuration in sonar or jacoco?

Comment: Which goal do you call with maven?

Comment: This is mvn cmd `mvn -B clean verify sonar:sonar -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -DskipLongRunningTests=false -DskipOpticalInterfaceTests=true -Dorg.xml.sax.driver=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=#### -Dsonar.analysis.mode=publish -Pjacoco`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to parse JaCoCo XML report: jacoco.exec
>   ...
>   Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1

The error indicates that unsupported character is found when parsing XML, and the file is `jacoco.exec`.
It is because `jacoco.exec` is binary, not xml.

In addition [Sonar has deprecated the support of jacoco.exec](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1651#).
I suggest you to follow [coverage-test-data-importing-jacoco-coverage-report-in-xml-format](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/coverage-test-data-importing-jacoco-coverage-report-in-xml-format/12151). 
From the link above:

> By default the generated report will be saved under **target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml**; this location will be checked automatically by the sonar-jacoco plugin so no further configuration is required. Just launch mvn sonar:sonar as usual and the report will be picked up.

Comment: Thanks @samabce, I don't get the exception now while parsing the xml file by removing the deprecated tags ...But even on successful parsing of file ...I don't get coverage as 0% in sonarqube result though it has UT in it  ```[INFO] 13:15:11.198 Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
[DEBUG] 13:15:11.204 Reading report '/udir/ragul/git/19/commons/access-commons-dao/target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml'
[INFO] 13:15:11.223 Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=25ms```

Comment: I suggest to open a new question for this problem.